# Why does a ListView need an adapter assigned to it

Tags: java, android

I know a list view needs an adapter, but WHY what is the purpose of it, and can it show lists without an adapter ?

Comment: Where would you provide the items and views for the listview to show otherwise?

Comment: what if i just want to show list, could i not use a simple string array for it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An adapter manages the data model and adapts it to the individual rows in the list view.

Filtering and sorting of the data is handled by the `adapter`.

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` method on the adapter is called if the data has changed or if new data is available.

The `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` method is called if the data is not available anymore.

Also see [What's the role of adapters in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674951/whats-the-role-of-adapters-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html):

> An `Adapter` object acts as a bridge between an `AdapterView` and the
>   underlying data for that view. The `Adapter` provides access to the data
>   items. The `Adapter` is also responsible for making a `View` for each item
>   in the data set.

The `ListView` needs to know which items to show, and needs to get `View`s for these items. The Android team chose to implement this using `Adapter`s.

---

Note that for showing simple lists of `String`s, there is the [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) class.