# Android: should a listView Adapter be part of your ViewModel class?

Tags: android, listview, mvvm, android-adapter

I am working on an Android Application and trying to follow MVVM design pattern. I have a listView and the question is whether the Adapter should be part of the ViewModel class? What is the best way to structure this with MVVM design pattern?

Answer (score -1):

I am new to Android development but from what I understand of the guidance I would suggest that the adapter should not know about the ViewModel. If the ViewModel knew about the adapter then it would know about the "tile" view.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674951/whats-the-role-of-adapters-in-android