# How to define a large group of imageViews?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 64 image view in android studio and I don't want to define them one by one like this:

```
ImageView iv11 = findViewById(R.id.iv11);
```

id of ImageViews start by iv11 (the first number is row and second col) and end with iv88 is there any way to define all of them together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Construct your `ImageView` id by for loops and call `getResources().getIdentifier()`

```
for (int col = 0 ; col < 8; ++col) {
    for (int row = 0 ; row < 8; ++row) {
        String idStr = "iv" + String.valueOf(row) + String.valueOf(col);
        @IdRes int id = context.getResources().getIdentifier(idStr, "id", context.getPackageName());

        ImageView imgView = findViewById(id);
        // Do something with your image
    }
}
```

Anyway, with that much `ImageView` on screen, it should be managed by an adapter like `ListView`, `RecyclerView`...

Answer (score 0):

You should populate your views with an [adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674951/whats-the-role-of-adapters-in-android?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Since it sounds like you need the images to be displayed in a grid, you could use [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview) with an adapter.

There are lot of tutorials that would guide you to do this; eg: you can look at [this](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) for a start.

Hope this helps.